# My arraylist is adding thousands of objects to itself

Tags: java, arraylist

I did a `System.out.println` of the `tileList.size()` and it is returning an int in thousands that quickly goes up as time progresses. I'm doing a Java applet where it creates tiles and randomly generates object variables for each spot in the ArrayList.

I don't know why this happens, but I could periodically clear the array list but I shouldn't have to.

```
col = 20;
row = 10;

public void createTiles()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= col; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= row; j++)
        {
            if (r.nextInt(100) >= slides / 2)
            {
                tileList.add(new Tile(i * 64, j * 64, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), false, 0, false));
            }

            if (r.nextInt(100) <= slides / 2)
            {
                tileList.add(new Tile(i * 64, j * 64, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), true, 0, false));
            }

            if (r.nextInt(500) <= 1)
            {
                tileList.add(new Tile(i * 64, j * 64, this.getHeight(), this.getWidth(), false, 0, true));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where it is being called from

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    createTiles();

    generatePanel();
    createSnowballs();
    createFish();
    penguinCollision();

    drawTiles(g);

    bearAI();
    bearCollision();
    drawSnowballs(g);
    drawFish(g);
    drawPenguin(g);
    drawHunger(g);
    drawHungerBar(g);
    drawBear(g);


    if (hungerAmount <= 0)
        drawGameover(g);
}
```

Comment: You don't need empty `else` blocks. You can just leave those out.

Comment: how/ where are you calling this? I suspect that your calling method is being called a lot. Stick a breakpoint on it and trace it's usage through...

Comment: it is being called from my paint method, is this why?

Comment: You're creating new tiles every time `paint` is called and never removing the old ones. Do you need new tiles every time?

Comment: only need new tiles when I move off the screen, i clear the array list everytime I go off screen

Answer (score 3):

In `java Applet's Paint` method is called infinite number of times to provide an consistent UI for user , just try it out by adding System.out.println() inside Paint,
So avoid calling those methods inside `Paint`.

Comment: Where should I call the methods? I am doing an applet so there is no main method.

Comment: Does the createtiles() method need's to be called only once then add it to init() or else use some flag's to decide when to call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tileList is a member of your class and when you call createTiles() you add Tiles to this list. If you call createTiles() multiple times the Tiles will add multiple time. I think that you sholud put

tileList = new ArrayList();

or

tileList.clear();

at the first line of your createTiles() method to reinitialize it or clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `createTiles()` method from the `init()` or `create()` methods. You list contains very large number of tiles because in applet, `paint()` method is called all the time. Also you are not supposed to override the `paint()` method. In swing based programs, you are advised to override the `paintComponent()` method instead.

Applets are getting old and they won't be supported in the future Java versions. I recommend switch to an application.

Comment: Would Jframe be a better alternate route then?